# How to draw an double type 2D Image to an Axis Handle In matlabUI

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I have a double 2D image that I want to use in my UI that I made with guide.  I have a axis handle which I want to draw it to.  I tried this with no success, my image is all blue.

```
    function ComputeMap_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to ComputeMap (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global healthyImage;
global sickImage;
global tumorMapImage;
global costFunction;
if(get(handles.radiobuttonMSE,'Value') == get(hObject,'Max'))
    costFunction = 0;

else

    costFunction = 1;
end
disp(costFunction);
tumorMapImage = mexFunction(im2double(sickImage),im2double(healthyImage),get(handles.blockSize,'Value'),get(handles.windowSize,'value'), costFunction);

image(tumorMapImage,'parent',handles.sImageGUI);
```

This mexFunction returns a double 2D image.  If I just call this function without matlab and imShow (resultImage); I get the right result.  So I believe it has something to do with the colormapping of the double and the fact that the image is not 3D but 2D.  But I am 0 familiar with gui in matlab to be sure what to do.  I've done some more researches and I think my problem might be related to the AlphaData property, but I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: Can you provide any additional code you are using or any errors you get? Does anything happen when you call that function? That line should otherwise work.

Comment: Added the stuff, I do not have any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your image values must be in range [0, 1] in order to be plotted properly by the `image` function.

`imshow` works because it first looks at the **min and max value** in your image and  then scales values to match this range. or so. (maybe it works differently internally, but whatever..)

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not the problem, I've had this problem before and it returns an error saying that the maximum value is over 1.0

Comment: ah ok, but you're aware that you still need to make sure that your lowest value is actually 0 and your highest value is acutally 1, right? i.e. if you have values around 1e-38 it will just display it as (almost pretty much) zero => blue.

Comment: Now that I read his question again, I am pretty certain this is the problem.  
@Apoc, try using `imagesc()` instead of `image()`.